# Get the data of the selected dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I get the value of my product_rate and put it inside my disabled input field when I choose or select a product in my dropdown.

[image]

[image]

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbselectedropdown");

    if (!$con) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Selected Dropdown</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="product_select" id="product_select">
        <option>--SELECT--</option>
        <?php
           $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tbselectedropdown");
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                echo "<option>" .$row["product_name"]. "</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="product_inputfield" id="product_inputfield" disabled/>
</body>
<script>

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, improve PHP:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tbselectedropdown");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo "<option value=" . $row["product_rate"] . ">" .$row["product_name"]. "</option>";
}
```

Second, add script:

```
<script>
  var input = document.getElementById('product_select')
  input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('product_inputfield').value = e.value
  })
</script>
```

Or, if you are using jQuery :)

```
<script>
  $('#product_select').change(function () {
    $('product_inputfield').val($(this).val())
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much. I didn't know it is ok to put fetch a data and put it inside the value. Haha.

Comment: @FrancisJohnVargas It is OK :) And simple, as you can see :)

Comment: Yeah, though I've used jQuery in that. Haha. Btw, I can't like your answer from now. It says after 10 minutes, I really appreciate your help. Thank you again.

Comment: @FrancisJohnVargas You can use jQuery, but with PHP improvement (adding value attribute) as first step, JS (jQuery) code can be simplier.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use JQuery if you are already using, it's fairly simple. Listen to any changes, and if there's a change add the text to the disabled input.

```js
// create new function on change of select input
$('#product_select').change(function() {
  // create variable for product
  var product = $("#product_select").find(':selected').text();
  // create an input variable
  var input = $("#product_inputfield");
  
  // for testing you can output the select
  alert('Changed value: ' + product);
  
  // create the if statements
  if(product === 'acer') {
    input.val(1500); // change the value with your PHP
    // <?=$row['product_rate'];?>
  } else if( product === 'samsung') {
    input.val(3200);
  } else if( product === 'lenovo' ) {
    input.val(5300);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Selected Dropdown</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="product_select" id="product_select">
        <option value="">--SELECT--</option>
        <option value="acer">acer</option>
        <option value="samsung">samsung</option>
        <option value="lenovo">lenovo</option>
    </select><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="product_inputfield" id="product_inputfield" readonly/>
</body>
<script>

</script>
</html>
```